# Angular promise - provide catch function

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am trying to come up with a generic service that would run my http requests and provides placeholders for success and error functions. Here is my code:

```
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 var response = $http({
  ..............
 });
 response.then(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data.data);
 });
 response.catch(function (data) {
        alert('Error');
 });
```

And in Controller:

```
service.executeHTTPCall('parameters').then(successHandler);
```

My question is how do I provide an error handler for an executeHTTPCall call?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, avoid the [explicit construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) and things fall into place:

```
// no deferred, just return
return $http({..... }).then(function(data){
    // handle successes
    return data.data;
}, function(err){ // handle failures here
     alert("ERrror!!!"); // logic here
     return $q.reject(err); // this is important, like a `catch and throw` 
                            // to signal we're still handling errors.
});
```

But, may I suggest [http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) instead?

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    'response': function(response) {
       // do something on success
    }, 
    'responseError': function(rejection) {
       // do something on failure, see docs for more usage examples here
    };
});
```

That would mean you can avoid wrapping every $http promise manually and also play nicer with tests.

Comment: I have never done http interceptors. May I ask for an example?

Comment: I linked to one in the answer, here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Comment: I have modified my service to your no deferred suggestion. Seems like I am getting data in success function of the service. But I am not getting into the success function when I call my service as I showed in my original code.

Comment: @Mark are you using `return` correctly there as in the docs? Also, don't use `success` and `failure`, use `then` and `catch`.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't using the return correctly. But I am having another problem. While I am getting into controller's success handler the data there is an object but it used to be an array. I am returning data.data from the service and it's an array.

Comment: Yes, since there is more than the data to the response it resolves to an object with a `.data` property. This is why I have the  `return data.data`  in the wrapper example.

Comment: Exactly what I am doing. I am returning data.data as well. response.then(function (data) {
            return data.data;
        });
        response.catch(function (data) {
            $q.reject(data.data);
        });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89775/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-mark).